# Location of Maven in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

In our organization, we have a machine that is configured to run our jenkins jobs.
There are two versions here.

1. In this version, a maven template is used for new item, and the repository name and settings.xml and pom.xml files locations are specified. And after this build step, I have `mvn -version` which gives some version and the location of the maven version. This works fine.
2. In this version, a pipeline template is used for new item. When I run the `mvn -version`, it doesn't have the path set for maven so it says mvn command not found. So I take the path from the previous version, and plug it here for maven in the path. Now I run the `path/to/maven/mvn -version` command, it says `JAVA_HOME` is not defined. When I execute the `export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java` the `JAVA_HOME` path is not set(may be the reason might be I don't have the rights to set environment variables).

So how do I run the `maven clean install` using the pipeline version (I dont have permission to install plugins also)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to not have the rights to set environment variables, but I may be wrong.

Comment: how have you taken the PATH for maven ?? using tool ?? also you should be able to set env variables when doing sh ... you can confirm it by doing an echo PATH and find the java location